Ansible to Python: Error decoding JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
In my Ansible config I have the following:
new_attributes:
  tenantID: "4234iugob8y8l3-8809yo3x"
  new_attribute2: "value2"

and the following in my tasks:
"{{ new_attributes | to_json }}"

and this in my Python script to access it:
    try:
        new_attributes = json.loads(new_attributes)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Error decoding JSON: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)


but I get the following error:
"stderr_lines": [],
"stdout": "Error decoding JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)",
"stdout_lines": ["Error decoding JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"]}

I am wondering if anyone can please help fix this.
update:
error output:
Error decoding JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"

and output from the to_json on the ansible side:
msg": "{\"tenantID\": \"4234iugob8y8l3-8809yo3x\", \"new_attribute2\": \"value2\"}

This is how i am parsing to python:
        - name: Debug new_attributes as JSON
          debug:
            msg: "{{ new_attributes | to_json }}"

        - name: Insert data into DynamoDB for client "{{ client_name }}"
          command: >
            python3 dynamodb_insert_or_update.py
            "{{ dynamodb_table_name }}"
            "{{ client_name }}"
            "{{ applicationID }}"
            "{{ new_attributes | to_json }}"
            "{{ aws_region }}"
            "{{ aws_profile }}"
          args:
            chdir: "/mypath/scripts/"
          register: result
          loop: "{{ clients }}"
          loop_control:
            loop_var: item


and my python script in full:
import sys
import boto3
import json

def insert_data(dynamodb_table_name, client_name, item_id, new_attributes, aws_region, aws_profile):
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_profile, region_name=aws_region)
    dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table(dynamodb_table_name)

    item = {
        'client_name': client_name,
        'applicationID': item_id
    }

    try:
        new_attributes = json.loads(new_attributes)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Error decoding JSON: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

    item.update(new_attributes)

    try:
        response = table.put_item(Item=item)
        print(f"Insert successful: {response}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to insert item: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

# Command-line arguments
dynamodb_table_name = sys.argv[1]
client_name = sys.argv[2]
item_id = sys.argv[3]
new_attributes = sys.argv[4]
aws_region = sys.argv[5]
aws_profile = sys.argv[6]

# Call the insert function
insert_data(dynamodb_table_name, client_name, item_id, new_attributes, aws_region, aws_profile)




Can you show output of :
except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
print(new_attributes)
print(f"Error decoding JSON: {e}")
sys.exit(1)

@YassineLbk, added

It appears you are parsing the human readable output of an Ansible debug task which contains more than just the content of your variable. How exactly are you passing the content between Ansible and your python script? Please do not answer in comments: [edit] your question and make it a correct [mre]

@Zeitounator added the task and the python script in full

Just run your playbook with -vvv and check what are the raw params sent to command. You are basically enclosing a double quoted string (the json payload) in double quotes. An easy fix is just to change double to single quotes for that param in your command => '{{ new_attributes | to_json }}'

EDIT:
By writing the command name followed by a list of space-delimited arguments (as per documentation) it should work.
These are the scripts I used to test locally:
test.yml
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
    new_attributes:
      tenantID: "4234iugob8y8l3-8809yo3x"
      new_attribute2: "value2"
  tasks:
  - name: Debug new_attributes as JSON
    debug:
      msg: "{{ new_attributes }}"
  - name: Run Python script using command module
    command:
      argv:
        - python3
        - myscript.py
        - "{{ new_attributes | to_json }}"

myscript.py
import sys
import json

# Load the argument as JSON
data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])

This does not work and gives the error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1):
  - name: Run Python script using command module
    command: >
      python3 myscript.py "{{ new_attributes | to_json }}"


The output from the debugging
- name: Debug new_attributes as JSON
    debug:
      msg: "{{ new_attributes | to_json }}"

should be "msg": "{\"tenantID\": \"4234iugob8y8l3-8809yo3x\", \"new_attribute2\": \"value2\"}" (with escaped quotes), which can be parsed by json.loads().
Check if the Python command works with the Python version configured for Ansible (use ansible --version to find out which one it is), it might be that Ansible is using an older Python.

Ansible is using the latest version of ansible,  also if I pass it in hard coded like this:
"{"tenantID": "4234iugob8y8l3-8809yo3x", "new_attribute2": "value2"}"
then it works fine as well, its just when I use "{{ new_attributes | to_json }}" it makes the error

@Talktomegoose I tested it with ansible [core 2.13.1], Python version = 3.9.7 and jinja version = 3.1.2

The output of debugging is actually not the problem as OP since clarified he is passing the variable directly to his python script (and not some registered one).
